# Bulk Edit Title field in team foundation server

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm currently working on Microsoft Team Foundation Server.
There are around 300 backlog items.
I need to append the word "User Story:" to the title field of all the backlog items. How to do this?

thanks.

Comment: Why? Each work item has a "type" field that says what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update multiple items in bulk by opening up the query in Microsoft Excel, update the title in excel and then use the Publish option in the Team menu item

[image]